# How do I send my own ID per transaction when using the BlueSnap Payment API?

Tags: payment-gateway, bluesnap

I am integrating with BlueSnap using their Payment API and want to assign my own transaction ID to each transaction. Is that possible with BlueSnap?

Answer (score 3):

Yes BlueSnap supports assigning a merchant specific transaction ID to each transaction.

To do this you will need to include the `merchant-transaction-id` element within the `card-transaction` element.

For example:

```
<card-transaction xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
   <card-transaction-type>AUTH_CAPTURE</card-transaction-type>
   <merchant-transaction-id>myUniqueMerchantTransactionId</merchant-transaction-id>
   <recurring-transaction>ECOMMERCE</recurring-transaction>
   <soft-descriptor>DescTest</soft-descriptor>
   <amount>11.00</amount>
   <currency>USD</currency>
   <card-holder-info>
      <first-name>test first name</first-name>
      <last-name>test last name</last-name>
   </card-holder-info>
   <credit-card>
      <card-number>4263982640269299</card-number>
      <security-code>837</security-code>
      <expiration-month>02</expiration-month>
      <expiration-year>2018</expiration-year>
   </credit-card>
</card-transaction>
```

You can see also in the documentation here: 
http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/auth-capture#section-auth-capture-with-merchant-transaction-id